# Increase the count of duplicates on the original record and delete the duplicates (Handle bulk import) in Salesforce

Tags: trigger

**While creating a contact, if you find the duplicate with reference to email on a new record, make an increment of count on original Record and delete the duplicate contact record**.

This code is increasing the count with single record when I insert from UI, but it is not working if insert using **Data Loader**( Though it has 10 duplicates but it is increasing the count as 1 ).

**Can anyone of you help me in providing the solution for handling bulk import ?**

```
public class JadeTest1 {

public static void deleteDuplicaRec1(List<Contact1__c> newList){
    Set<Id> newConIds= new Set<Id>();
    Set<String> newEmails = new Set<String>();
    for(Contact1__c newRec : newList){
        newEmails.add(newRec.Email__c);
        newConIds.add(newRec.Id);
    }
    Map<String, Id> dupMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(Contact1__c dup : [SELECT Id,Name , Email__c FROM Contact1__c WHERE Email__c IN : newEmails]){
        if(!newConIds.contains(dup.id)){
            dupMap.put(dup.Email__c, dup.Id);
        }
    }

    List<Id> dupIds = new List<Id>();
    for(Contact1__c c: newList){
        system.debug('New rec' + c.Name);
        Id dupId = dupMap.get(c.Email__c);
        if(dupId!=null && newConIds.contains(c.id)){
            dupIds.add(dupId);
            system.debug(' dup list' + dupIds);
        }
    }
    List<Contact1__c> updateCon = new List<Contact1__c>();
    for(Contact1__c c : [SELECT Id, Name,Count__c FROM Contact1__c WHERE ID IN : dupIds]){
        system.debug('duplicate rec' + c.Name);
        c.Count__c = c.Count__c+1;
        updateCon.add(c);
    }
    update updateCon;
    del_DupRec(newConIds);
}
@future
public Static void del_DupRec (Set<Id> dupIds){
    List<Contact1__c> dup = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact1__c WHERE ID IN: dupIds];
    system.debug('future debug '+ dup);
    delete dup;
}        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with below line of code.

```
Map<String, Id> dupMap = new Map<String, Id>();
    for(Contact1__c dup : [SELECT Id,Name , Email__c FROM Contact1__c WHERE Email__c IN : newEmails]){
        if(!newConIds.contains(dup.id)){
            dupMap.put(dup.Email__c, dup.Id);
        }
    }
```

Maps can have a single unique key. As I can see that you are putting email as key.

So if there are 10 duplicates, dupMap will have only one entry as the other 9 record also have a same email id.

The solution will be to change your approach.

dupMap should be of type.

*`Map<String, List<Id>> dupMap = new Map<String, List<Id>>();`*

Your code will look like.

```
    Map<String, List<Id>> dupMap = new Map<String, List<Id>>();
for(Contact1__c dup : [SELECT Id,Name , Email__c FROM Contact1__c WHERE Email__c IN : newEmails]){
        if(!newConIds.contains(dup.id)){
            if(dupMap.contains(dup.Email__c)){
                dupMap.get(dup.Email__c).add(dup.Id);
            }else{
                dupMap.put(dup.Email__c,new List<Id>{dup.Id});
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: How will I find out the original Id using Map of List of Id's from your logic snippet